# JQuery validation plugin and custom rule

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jquery.validation plugin in my web app.
I have this general code for form validation:

```
$('form[data-toggle="validator"]').each(function () {
            $(this).validate({
                errorClass: "help-block error",
                errorElement: "div",
                focusCleanup: false,
                focusInvalid: false,
                submitHandler: function(form){
                    $("[type=submit]",form).prop("disabled",true);
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
         });
```

When I need the validation I just set the data-toggle attribute to the form.

In a particular case I would like to add a custom rule, not for a single input element, but for all the form.
I would like to add it at runtime, is it possibile?

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do here?  The accepted answer seems to have absolutely nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I need to check some values not strictly connected to a single element and moreover I need to add this rule runtime after the code above, how to do this with jquery validation?

Comment: It's still somewhat unclear.  When you create a custom rule/method, it's then available to be declared on any one or more input elements.  The custom rule/method is not specifically tied to any one element.  Is this what you meant by *"custom function"*?

Comment: For custom function I mean a no standard rule like digits, email, url and so on.

Comment: In that case, it helps greatly to use to standard language... it's called a custom "method" or "rule".

Comment: done (I used function because in javascript language the method declaration has the "function" keyword)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are searching for method to add a custom validation method.
Below is the example where I add a validation to check for max length for a value at runtime.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("maxLengthName", function(value, element) {
  return value.length>30;
}, 'Please enter a name with length less than 30.');
```

> value :- the current value of the validated element 
> element :- the
>   element to be validated

**Update**

The above way is to add a custom method for a single input element. 
Now the question remains how can we do same for form and not just 1 input element.

> No, we cannot add a custom rule to the `<form>` element

But there is a way you can add a single rule for multiple inputs. Below is the example for same. In this example we check if addition of `Input 1` and `Input 2` is equal to `Total` entered by user

```
<form id="TotalForm" name="TotalForm">
    <label>Input 1</label>
    <input type="text" name="inputone" id="inputone" class="required" />
    <label>Input 2</label>
    <input type="text" name="inputTwo" id="inputTwo" class="required" />
    <label>Total</label>
    <input type="text" name="inputTotal" id="inputTotal" class="required totalMatch" />
</form>


jQuery.validator.addMethod("totalMatch",function(value) {
        total = parseFloat($('#inputone').val()) + parseFloat($('#inputTwo').val());
        return total == parseFloat($('#inputTotal').val());
    }, "Total is not matching with Input 1 and  Input 2!");

    jQuery.validator.classRuleSettings.totalMatch = { totalMatch: true };
```

Now you can call validate on document.ready function like below and

```
$("#TotalForm").validate();
```

Comment: Ok, but can I add this method to the <form> element for a global validation?

Comment: @Tobia I think it should not be a issue.. but not sure what will value have in it and when will it get propogated..

Comment: @Tobia, this simply shows how to write a custom rule, which needs to be declared on each input element, so I don't see how this answers your question: *"I would like to add a custom function, **not for a single input element, but for all the form**. I would like to add it at runtime, is it possible?"*

Comment: No, you cannot add a custom rule to the `<form>` element and the original question is unclear.

Comment: There were two answer: how to add rule runtime and how to add a global rule to the form (not for particular input). The first is answered, the second not yet (and the answer seems to be "no"). If the question is unclear please edit it.

Comment: @Tobia, if the question is not fully solved, then you should not have accepted an answer.   Because of this, others will not know you're still seeking help and have no incentive to add another answer.  As far as expecting somebody else to fix your question; how could anybody else know what you really want to do when it's written unclear in the first place?

Comment: @Sparky thanks for your valuable inputs , I have updated my answer to address the complete question and not just part of it.

Comment: @Tobia  I have updated my answer to address the complete question and also provided you with an option to do something I think you want when you say _adding a custom function to a form_. You can re accept my answer if it helps you in resolving your question